# Proof that $((A\setminus B)\setminus (B\setminus C))^{c} = A^{c} \cup B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm lost in this question, how can I deal with multiple complements and differences?

Comment: Hello @João Eduardo, welcome to MSE. It is customary to write your question in the post as well, not only in the title. Also, can you please add in the question what you tried yourself and where exactly you got stuck? That way, it will be easier for others to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, notice that there are no points in common between $A\setminus B$ and $B\setminus C$.  So $$(A\setminus B) \setminus (B\setminus C)=A\setminus B \quad (*)$$

Next, notice that in general for sets, $$ X \setminus Y = X \cap Y^{c} \quad (**)$$

Finally, we have a basic fact of set theory (draw a picture and you can see it), that the compliment of the intersection is the union of the compliments: $$ (X \cap Y)^{c}=X^{c} \cup Y^{c} \quad (***)$$

So to answer your question,
$$ ((A\setminus B) \setminus (B\setminus C))^{c} \overset{(*)}{=} (A\setminus B)^{c} \overset{(**)}{=} (A\cap B^{c})^{c} \overset{(***)}{=}A^{c} \cup B$$